# Breakpoints not getting hit in Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, debugging, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

My breakpoints aren't getting hit in Xamarin Studio. I'm not sure if this has to do with my code, or not, but I feel as though it doesn't because I've tried over and over putting breakpoints all over my project (in places where I know they should definitely be hit, and in places that the code works perfectly and is completely unrelated to the feature I'm currently testing) and none of them are getting acknowledged when I debug. I don't have the breakpoints disabled, and I don't have them added in the wrong place. The breakpoints should work normally, and they're not. I'll also add that I'm not allowed to pause my application during the debugging process. I suppose you could say the debugger in my Xamarin Studio isn't working and I have no idea why. I believe I've determined it's unrelated to the code, but I can't be sure about that still. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Are you in Release mode? If not try restarting Xamarin Studio and if this does not help, perhaps reinstalling everything Xamarin related ...

Comment: Try clean and rebuild your solution

Comment: Another similar question was resolved by not selecting bundle all assemblies to native code

Comment: I suggest to mark the @rvnlord answer as an answer.

Answer (score 20):

It is the most popular question about: "breakpoints are not being hit in xamarin" in google, so after whole day of trial and error I am gonna post here a solution for this problem for xamarin versions > 4.0.0.xxx. Yes, sadly this is simple.

**SOLUTION**
(This solution is for android app in visual studio, but should work in xamarin studio as well)

Remove all symbols from the path to your "Debug" Folder (usually: [path to your .sln file] \ [your solution name] \bin\Debug):

So if you got for example:

```
G:\My Files\Programming\C# (+ JS)\Test1\Examples\LINQ to Objects\AndroidDemo\AndroidDemo\bin\Debug
```

Change it to:

```
G:\My Files\Programming\CSharp\Test1\Examples\LINQ to Objects\AndroidDemo\AndroidDemo\bin\Debug
```

For me "(" and ")" symbols were causing the trouble (Who is using such symbols in the path anyway right?)

To verify that this is working, open your debug folder, in VIsual Studio Select "Clean Solution", "Recompile Solution", "Deploy".

"Deploy" action should generate *.mdb files which include your debugging data. If they are present, you should now be able to stop at breakpoints.

Now you can simply hit F5 like usual whenever you need to debug something.

[image]

Comment: This also worked for me, but still I couldn't understand why this is causing such issue. Any idea??

Comment: You have got to be kidding me. It worked FINE an hour ago, and now it's suddenly an issue? This also resolved it for me. That's so weird, how it suddenly decides to break.

Comment: @JedatKinports I think simply the path to your solution. If you solution is in `C:\You\(Something-like-this)\app.sln` change it to `C:\You\Somethinglikethis\app.sln`.

Comment: @ispiro thanks. I figured it out, i also had dots and exclamation points in my path.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure if someone is still following this thread, but this workaround worked for me.
The problem sometimes has to do with the mono 5.

So the resolution is to use older version of mono:

Set "Project > Active Runtime" to "Mono 4.8.0 (8f6d0f6) (/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.0)".

for Mac users, change it in "Preferences" -> ".NET Runtimes"

Then Rebuild the Android app project.

Comment: I red this on the Xamarin forums as well, tried it and indeed it works for me (Xamarin Studio for Mac). I had to download and install Mono version 4.8.1 because I only had Mono 5.0.1.1 installed (fresh new mac).

Comment: This solution works in Visual Studio Community for Mac.

Comment: I  have changed the `.Net runtimes` as Mono `4.8.1` instead of `5.0.1.1` but this doesn't solve the problem. still break point is not triggering in `Droid` project

Comment: Worked for me as well. Thanx

Answer (score 3):

Deleting the BIN folders and any *.SUO file is a favorite fix for this issue.

Can also try deleting any *.csproj.user

In worst case, reset VS Settings by launching (Run) with "Devenv.exe /ResetSettings"

Comment: That works! Deleting SUO file in .vs directory helped! Also, for some reason this file doesn't appear anymore and debugger works.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have your build configuration set to Debug.
2. Make sure your project's build settings are set to allow emitting DEBUG symbols for your Debug configuration.
3. Clean and Rebuild your solution/project.
4. Close and restart Xamarin Studio.
5. Reboot your computer.

Sometimes the build configurations for your solution can get complicated, and it's easy to miss something when building a complex build configuration. Make sure everything is setup properly in there.

Comment: I tried this, but it didnt worked for me. Seems there is some problem with the XamarinStudio itself. Because this problem started occuring for me after installing an update of XamarinStudio.

Comment: Moreover the breakpoint is hit only for the main class of the program. If i put break point in some other classes, particularly the classed extended from an interface, the breakpoints are not hitting. Strange it is.

Comment: Are those classes that don't get hit in a project/library/assembly other than your main program? In other words, do you have more than one project in your solution? If so, are those other projects setup for debugging in your build configurations? This is the only reason I can think of that would cause that behavior. If you can hit breakpoints in some projects and not others, it's almost always a build configuration problem. It COULD be a problem with a Xam Studio update, but be sure to check build configs. Otherwise, submit a bug report.

Comment: Well, yes I have more than one projects in my solution. But I have set up those projects for debugging, still the break points are not hitting. And am sure it is an issue in XamarinStudio. Because the same project worked me before few updates(probably 1 or 2 updates from latest) of XamarinStudio.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your build configuration matrix?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this yesterday, using VS 2013 and Xamarin plugin. "All of a sudden" breakpoints in a PCL project were not active, even though breakpoints in an Android project still were. Everything had been working perfectly for weeks, and I had applied no updates. Looking at the VS Debug | Windows | Modules view, I could see that symbols were not loaded for the PCL assembly, and nothing I tried would force them to load, even though they were present in the folder with the running assemblies.

Then I remembered that the last thing I had done the prior day was not related to code, but was a bit of refactoring of csproj files to support a parameterized Jenkins build. I had placed an OutputPath definition in the first "shared" PropertyGroup, and removed it from all of the Configuration/Platform-specific PropertyGroups, e.g.:

```
<OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
```

I deleted this "common" OutputPath and put it back into each specific PropertyGroup (offending my DRY sensibilities, mind you), and things started working again.

This is probably not going to bite very many people, but it wasted a couple of my hours, so hopefully it spares someone else. The Xamarin build probably does some of its MSBuild/xbuild spelunking with strong expectations, so if you've modified your csproj files for a build process, this might be a possible culprit.

Answer (score 1):

I add this answer because this is the only one that worked for me, in `Project Properties > Build` I wrongly checked `Optimize Code`.
Unchecking this box solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I switched from stable to alpha Channel v.3.11.785 (Alpha). all breakpoints are now hit.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem in Xamarin Forms app using Visual Studio for Mac. In my case, it was happened because of debugger. Visual studio was continuously showing "Waiting for the debugger to connect to the iOS simulator..." while running in an iOS simulator. I did reset the simulator (**Hardware** **=>** **Erase** **All** **Content** **and** **Settings**) and cleaned up the solution. Then I could do the debugging with breakpoints. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.

**THE CAUSE (IMO):**

In my case the problem is caused by Xamarin Studio (but with VS2013 is the same) build/rebuild process.

More in details, the *.mdb files are not correctly regenerated and therefore the debugger does not work properly.
You can check by doing a solution clean and going to bin/debug folder: if you still see *.mdf files then that's the problem in your case too!

**SOLUTION**

The only solution that works well is to manually delete all *.mdb files in bin/debug from all projects in your solution (so Android project and all PCL projects) and then do a Rebuild.

**Let me know if this helps!**

Comment: FWIW:  I did delete all of the mdb files, and cleaned and rebuild the projects.  I still have the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

For me "(" and ")" symbols were also causing the trouble, I was searching for weeks for this problem. Remove the "(" and ")" in the full path, do a clean build and de breakpoints are hit again.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, xamarin was not hitting any breakpoint. Red color rings were shown instead of filled red circles, because there were some syntax errors not able to be pointed out by xamarin, since I think solution build was not *up to date*, even I was able to run the app surprisingly. So I *cleaned* and *build* the solution, and it pointed out errors and relevant warnings after that. I fixed those, and ran the project. I was able to debug successfully after that!

Answer (score -1):

If once the project launches on the device VS reverts to the standard editing mode (no debug options enabled in the menu) i.e. the debugger is not attached; check Project Properties > Android Options > **Enable developer instrumentation** is **checked**. For me the setting was disabled (most likely checked into source control after a release).

Answer (score -1):

**Use "Visual Studio for Mac" (Preview at the moment but works) instead of "Xamarin Studio".** This fixed the problem for me. Breakpoints are working even in my PCL projects! Another thing... I had to change "project.json" (JSON format) to "packages.config" (XML format) when changing from "Xamarin Studio" to "Visual Studio for Mac".