# Xamarin iOS debugger not hitting breakpoints

Tags: ios, debugging, xamarin, breakpoints

Yesterday morning as I started working on a Xamarin iOS application when my debugger stopped working. I can place breakpoints but as soon as the application starts the breakpoints become hollow like a red donut. I've rebuilt/cleaned project multiple times, I've also wiped obj/bin folders and nothing seems to work. I can't hit breakpoints.

This doesn't happen to all my classes, it looks like it applies to classes where an async function is used however this isn't always the case.

I also get a message in my debugger window which may have only started showing since this bug.

Xamarin.iOS: Successfully received USB connection from the IDE on port 10000, fd: 7
Xamarin.iOS: Processing: 'start profiler: no'
Xamarin.iOS: Profiler not loaded (disabled)

I'm using Xamarin Studio 6.0.1 Build 9 Indie

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Breakpoints not getting hit in Xamarin Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29507113/breakpoints-not-getting-hit-in-xamarin-studio)

Answer (score 2):

I have found solution related to this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34211506/4627978.

Also be sure, that you set Debug configuration in Xamarin Studio (not Release, AppStore, etc.) and enable debugging in **Project Options > Build > iOS Debug > Enable debugging**

After all this don't forget Clean/Rebuild.

Comment: The solution you linked me has no effect on my case as all my project names are english characters, not even a single space.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and I got it working after changing the iOS project property Linker Behavior to Don't Link.

Make sure you have the iOS SDK updated to what you have in Xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution for Visual Studio:

1. Right-click your project -> Properties
2. iOS Debug
3. Enable debugging (and perhaps also Debugging over WiFi)