# Xamarin breakpoints not being hit

Tags: c#

I can't hit breakpoints in Xamarin for Visual Studio. The question appears to be answered for me here [Breakpoints not getting hit in Xamarin Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29507113/breakpoints-not-getting-hit-in-xamarin-studio) as I have a character in my file path, what the solution doesn't explain is how to change the path to the debug folder. If I simply rename it, that creates a conflict, and the solution will not build. Any help greatly accepted, I restarted work on the a project that was working fine when I left it three months ago and it has placed one obstacle in front of another ever since.

Comment: clean your project and rebuild and try again

Comment: check if the target framework or visual studio version changed. if then open the solution folder and delete folder named `.vs`

Comment: I have cleaned and rebuilt, how do I know if the target framework or VS version has changed, I doubt they have because I haven't used them since.